# Handling Many Spinners in an Activity

Tags: android

In my activity I have 10 Spinners and I want to get the `itemSelected` from each one and put it in a string value. Is there any other method than using `onItemSelectedListner` for each Spinner. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

you can use swith statement

```
switch(parentitem.getId()) {
    ...//your code here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

### Example :

```
String custommerName = ""; 
customerSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                        custommerName = nameItems.get(i).getName(); //to get name selected in spinner

            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {

            }
        });
```

now, you can use custommerName to set any value.